# Hive - Ignore missing partitions

Tags: hive

Someone has greatly messed up one of the tables in our database. There are many pages of missing partitions. Is there any way to query that table, ignoring the missing partitions? I detected them via:

```
msck repair table <myTableName>;
OK
Partitions missing from filesystem:  <lots of stuff>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the table is `EXTERNAL`, you can `DROP+CREATE+REPAIR.`

If it's not, copy/move the data to a location outside the hive warehouse, `DROP+CREATE`, and load the data back on. (and ask yourself if there's any good reason to be using internal tables).

Comment: I had to hack a script to drop each individually. There's no magic command :(

Comment: As of now, we should repair with "msck repairt table XXXX", but my questions are performance or effects of hive query(regular batch) with missing partitions. Is there any cases about lower performance or unexpected effects with missing partitions? and Is really necessary to do "DROP+CREATE", not "REPAIR" only?